# Разбить строку на символы и превратить в List

Tags: массивы, java

Привет. Почему не работает такой код?

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s = reader.readLine();
        List<Character> chars = new ArrayList<Character>(Arrays.asList(s.toCharArray()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Он у вас не то что не работает, а даже не компилируется.

Метод `BufferedReader.readLine` выбрасывает неконтролируемое исключение, которое вы обязаны обработать в вашем коде.

Метод `Arrays.asList` ожидает в вашем случае `Character[]`, а вы передаете ему `char[]`. В таких случаях autoboxing не работает.

Comment: А как сделать из char[] Character[]?

Comment: @Dazar Поэлементно.

Comment: @a_gura, ну тогда уже проще не возится с Arrays.asList, а сразу 
    for(char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        list.add(c);
    }

Comment: @Dazar именно.

Comment: @a_gura, в любом случае, спасибо, вопрос закрыт.